# Disable page swipe in specific ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I am loading a side menu view controller while in a controller using the github available project [ResideMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu)

It allows you to link a button to call the side menu or scroll from one side of the phone to bring up a menu.

I would like to disable that particular function only on the mainViewController.
The action for the menu is slide all the way from the left side of the phone to the right and it pulls up the side menu.

I am using navigation controller and storyboard

i would post the code but there is a lot of it, let me know if i should look for any particular code to post

Comment: It looks like the ResideMenu code has a delegate `willShowMenuViewController` that currently does not have a return value.  Maybe you could alter the provided code to have that delegate return a BOOL that will indicate whether to slide out the menu.  Then, in your ViewController that you do not want to enable the slide-out menu, you could implement the delegate call to simply return `NO`.

Comment: @wottle do you have a little snip it you could post? or show me where to find it? thanks

Comment: I may have time to try to whip something together tonight.  If so, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: There is one property : @property (assign, readwrite, nonatomic) BOOL panGestureEnabled; . And we can use that to enable or disable the swipe for the RESideMenu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this took a few more changes than I thought it would.  I created a sample project based off of the one provided with the RESideMenu in github.

https://github.com/wottle/REsideDemoWithOnOff

Open the project in the ExampleProjects directory to see how it works.

The basics of what I did are this:

Modified the existing protocol to return a BOOL for the `willShow...` methods.  In the implementation, I changed the code to check for the return value and that is what determines if the menu will show or now.  Then, because the showing and hiding of the menu is controlled by a root view controller (not each individual view controller), I created a new protocol that can optionally be implemented by each individual view controller you will display.

```
@protocol RESideViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (BOOL)shouldAllowMenu;
@end
```

Each of the view controllers conforms to this protocol, and for this case they implement it.  If they do not conform to the protocol, by default they will allow the menu to display. Here is how you would make your individual view controllers conform to the new protocol in the .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RESideMenu.h"

@interface DEMOFirstViewController : UIViewController <RESideViewDelegate>
    - (BOOL) shouldAllowMenu;

@end
```

and in the view controller's .m, provide the implementation of the shouldAllowMenu method:

```
#import "DEMOFirstViewController.h"

@interface DEMOFirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation DEMOFirstViewController


- (BOOL) shouldAllowMenu
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

In the second View controller, I return no.  So the first view controller allows the menu, the second one does not.

```
 - (BOOL) shouldAllowMenu
{
    return NO;
}
```

Then, in the root view controller's implementation of the `willShowMenuViewController`, I see if the current view controller conforms to the protocol, and if it does, call the method and pass that back to the RESideMenu.

```
- (BOOL)sideMenu:(RESideMenu *)sideMenu willShowMenuViewController:(UIViewController *)menuViewController
{
    NSLog(@"willShowMenuViewController: %@", NSStringFromClass([menuViewController class]));

    UINavigationController *navController = sideMenu.contentViewController;
    if( [navController.topViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(RESideViewDelegate) ])
    {
        UIViewController <RESideViewDelegate>*resideView = navController.topViewController;
        return [resideView shouldAllowMenu];
    }
    return NO;
}
```

I confirmed this works, but make take some effort to incorporate it into your project.  For the sake of tracking down my changes, I changed the RESideMenu.m and RESideMenu.h, and made the changes above to the root view controller, and the content view controllers.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for going through all of the code an not just telling me to do it myself

Comment: No problem.  I hadn't used the RESideMenu before, so I always enjoy seeing other people's components.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "ReSideMenu.h"


Add these two methods:

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.sideMenuViewController setPanGestureEnabled:NO];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.sideMenuViewController setPanGestureEnabled:YES];
}
```